# is it possible to keep the roxygen2 documentation in a file separate from the function?

Tags: r, documentation, roxygen2

My use case involves keeping the documentation for a package in one repo and the functions in a different package. Is that possible with roxygen2?

Comment: ........... Why?

Comment: There was a [recent blog post](https://www.enchufa2.es/archives/documenting-r-packages-roxygen2-vs-direct-rd-input.html) that discusses advantages or roxygen versus Rd files, and one of the clear (in my mind) advantages of roxygen is its adjacency to the code. The argument attributed to Duncan Murdoch is that using the LaTeX-like format helps, because it forces you to think about it (similar to chopsticks and non-sticky rice for those not comfortable with chopsticks?). By using simpler roxygen (even markdown) documentation in a different place, you are making it more likely to be out-of-sync.

Comment: I definitely agree with the points @r2evans makes.  Imagine you decide to add or remove a parameter from your function.  With your documentation *right there* you will be more likely to remember to add that change directly into the documentation.  I've written documentation both ways and I by far prefer the roxygen approach.

Comment: @Dason the explanation is kind of pedestrian: there is a group of non-technical people assisting with documentation, and we'd rather not have them editing the files with the functions.